# Backbone's change event for models and collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am searching online to no avail - what is the difference between:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add reset remove', this.render);
```

…and:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render);
```

I am trying to find out what the `change` event encapsulates. It's really hard to find this info.

Furthermore, in the `this.render` callback - how do I find out what was changed? Do I have to inspect the Backbone model/collection myself or is there a higher level way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The annotated Backbone source is really good for figuring out stuff like this.

According to http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-144 the 'change' event is fired whenever a model in the collection is changed.

The change event is triggered with the same arguments as if triggered on the model, where the model that is changed would be one of the arguments the event is triggered with (http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-73). You can check what was changed by calling changedAttributes on the model (http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-77). However, reset does not necessarily seem to trigger update either.

Add, reset and remove seems to be triggered in totally different cases than change for collection. You might be looking for "update" instead, which is triggered whenever the number of elements in the collection is changed: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-118

Comment: so given what you said, then this.listenTo(this.collection, 'change', this.render,this);, then in render:function(model){console.log(model)}; would log the model that changed.

Comment: but what I just said is not the case. I get 3 arguments in this.render.

Comment: One of the arguments should be the model at least.